# Crystal Reports for Enterprise 4.2 - List of Values & Dynamic Cascading Prompts not appearing in InteractiveViewer.jsp

Tags: jsp, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

We installed from scratch Crystal Reports for Enterprise 4.2 on a Windows Server 2012. The previous Crystal Server was 3.1 on Windows Server 2008.

We began having an issue on the new server where list of values (LOVs) and Dynamic Cascading Prompts (DCPs) are not populating for a third-party web app we are using. It worked fine in 3.1.

For example, in when the prompt group appears, Location should have a drop down with all the different location. There is no drop down to select from. If you manually enter a location, the report will render the report correctly.

[image]

In c:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\logging, there's a trace file (rptappserver_CRYSTAL4.CrystalReports2016ReportApplicationServer_trace.glf) with the following error:

```
|24f33a23-9c86-9f84-da13-a52a4138d52a|2016 05 03 11:12:27:666|-0700
|Error| |>>|E|
|rptappserver_CRYSTAL4.CrystalReports2016ReportApplicationServer|
432|10092|| ||||||||||||||||||||||
assert failure: (.\BELOVDataSource.cpp:1394). 
(false : BELOV: Caught COM exception when fetching data from RAS. - -2147467259).
```

Any thoughts on why the list of values or dynamic cascading prompts are not creating a drop down for me?

In Central Management Console (CMC) and BusinessInfoview (BI) Launch Pad shows the report correctly with the drop down values.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to turn Tracing to Medium for ReportApplicationServer. You log into CMC, go to Servers, then right click on Properties of ReportApplicationServer. Under Tracing, set it to Medium, then Apply.

Perform the actions again.

This time rptappserver.glf (generic log file) gave more details:

```
|c0c10044-cb05-bb44-1a65-5bdb7ef6851e|2016 05 02 14:50:10:865|-0700|Error| |>>|E| |
rptappserver_CRYSTAL4.CrystalReports2016ReportApplicationServer
|  432|8472|| ||||||||||||||||||||||assert failure:
(.\BELOVDataSource.cpp:1394). (false : BELOV: Caught COM exception 
when fetching data from RAS. - -2147467259).
.\errorutil.cpp:125:-: TraceLog message 6277
|06b9a34a-405a-7324-ead5-fd856ed78af7|2016 05 02 

14:50:10:865|-0700|Information| |==| | |
rptappserver_CRYSTAL4.CrystalReports2016ReportApplicationServer
|  432|8472|| ||||||||||||||||||||||
List of Values failure: fail to get values. [error source = prompt.dll;
file name = .\htmlrenderer2.cpp; line number = 3113; cause error = 
initializationEx  
SDKException:Sorry, you do not have the right to 'Edit objects' (ID: 6) 
for 'LOCATION_5' (ID: 19555). 
Please contact your administrator if you require this right.
```

This error lead me to install SAP Business View Manager (51050613_1\SBOP_BI_PLAT_4.2_SP2_CLNT_WIN_) and give the user that logs into Crystal Reports read and edit permission for those specific Dynamic Cascading Prompts (DCP).